# Which of the following pairs show common ion effect?

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium

> Which of the following pairs show common ion effect?
>
> 1. $\ce{BaCl2}$,$\ce{Ba(NO3)2}$
> 2. $\ce{NaCl}$, $\ce{HCl}$
> 3. $\ce{NH4OH}$,$\ce{NH4Cl}$
> 4. $\ce{NaOH}$, $\ce{NaCl}$

Its not (1) because they are both solids.

The remaining are solute solvent pairs. So all the other pairs will show common ion effect if the solute is soluble to some extent and exists in an equilibrium with the solvent. The answer given is (3). But why cant (2) and (4) show common ion effect?

Comment: It might be related to the fact that HCl and NaOH dissociate almost completely and there's no equilibrium in their dissociation reactions to shift.

Comment: I don't understand why you rule out (1). Why can't you have aq. BaCl2 and aq. Ba(NO3)2? If you say that both of them are solids, then you should also rule out (4), because both NaOH and NaCl exist as solids as well. Furthermore you should rule out (2) because HCl is gaseous and covalently bonded so there aren't even any ions to speak of. Apart from that, @IͶΔ has the right answer.

Comment: Note that the fictitious solid compound “ammonium hydroxide” $(\ce{NH4OH})$ does not exist.